# How to delete lnk files in desktop only from guest account in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8, shortcuts

I have a Windows 8 system and it has administrator and guest accounts. Whenever I install a program, its lnk file appears at desktop of both administrator and guest as usual. I don't need that lnk files on guest desktop. So I deleted it from guest desktop and when came to administrator desktop it all was gone from there too. So I restored it from recycle bin. Then it appeared at the guest desktop too.

I need to know that is there any way to remove the lnk files only from guest desktop. Or, is there any way not to appear them on guest desktop during installation ?

Comment: during setup, select to create shortcut only for current user, not for all.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thats a nice suggestion. But every program doesn't provide such a situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the program, a shortcut may be created in C:\Users\Public\Desktop, which is a hidden folder for all users desktop. If the shortcut is in this location, it will show up on everyone's desktop. If it is deleted it will not be on anyone's desktop. The best thing to do is to move it into your desktop folder located at C:\Users[Username]\Desktop.

Alternatively, you can put any file in C:\Users\Default\Desktop, which will make a copy of the file to each new account on first log on. Existing accounts will not get a copy of files copied to this location.